# show a PDE has no distribution solution in $\mathbb{R^2}$\{0}

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

" Consider the following equation in the plane

$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f(x^2+y^2)$

where $f(t)$ is a $C^\infty$ function of the real variable $t$ such that 
  $f(t)=0$  if $t$ < 1 or $t$ > 2,  and $f(3/2) = 1$.

Show that the equation has no distribution solution in $\mathbb{R^2}$\{0}. "

This is the question 2.1 in the book basic linear partial differential equations by Francois Treves. I'm reading the book this summer. He gives the hint that rewrite $\iint |f(x^2+y^2)|^2 dx dy$  by introducing u, assumed to satisfy the equation.

I'm a beginner of the distribution theory and actually I don't know how to approach this problem even with the hint, because I even don't know whether the equation has a smooth solution. In view of the form of the hint, I cannot help using Plancherel Theorem, but it only works for $L^2$,  and I don't know how to do the Fourier Transform on a distribution. All I know about is the Fourier Transform on a tempered distribution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a **hint** to get you started. What you know is that $\iint_D |f(x^2+y^2)|^2\,dx\,dy > 0$ for $D$ a disk centered at the origin of radius $3$, say. Rewrite this integral (assuming $f\ge 0$) by switching to polar coordinates:
$$\iint_D |f(x^2+y^2)|^2\,dx\,dy = \iint_D f(x^2+y^2)\left(x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) dx\,dy = \iint_D f(r^2)\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}\,r\,dr\,d\theta.$$
Now apply Green's Theorem (integration by parts) in an appropriate way to show that this integral is $0$, thereby arriving at a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really a smart idea. I was intimidated by the word "distribution" at first. I think the validity of the second equation is because of the general chain rule. I found the proof on https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch3.pdf, which uses the fact that $C^\infty$ functions are dense in Soblev spaces. And to apply the integration by parts is trivial because of the definition of the derivative of a distribution. Thus the integral is 0. Am I correct?